# Does Kamisama Kiss pass the Bechdel test?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

> The Bechdel test asks if a work of fiction features at least two women who talk to each other about something other than a man. The requirement that the two women must be named is sometimes added. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test

I'd like to know if this series passes the test and what was the scene that makes the series pass test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, while [bechdeltest.com](http://bechdeltest.com/) exists as a database for movies that pass and do not pass the test, at the moment no equivalent can be found for anime/manga.

The manga passes the test in the second chapter: the main character meets an old woman lying outside who tells her she has sprained her legs, so she helps the woman to the woman's home, where she is invited to stay for the night, as the main character was left homeless in the first chapter.

That's as far as I read, so there may be more passing conversations.

Keep in mind that while the Bechdel test has been used as an indicator of gender bias or feminist litmus test in works of fiction, it doesn't really prove much aside from the presence of female characters. Plenty of works with strong female characters fail the Bechdel test, and because the Bechdel test doesn't take into account the length, complexity, or subject of the conversation, works with one-dimensional female characters can pass easily as long as two women speak to each other about shoes or cooking or how they don't understand math or politics or something.

*Fifty Shades of Gray* passes the test, but has been blasted for glorifying abusive relationships. The movie *12 Angry Men*, widely regarded as one of the best films of all time, fails because it focuses on a 1950s-era jury, on which women did not serve. The entire *Lord of the Rings* series fails the test because none of the female characters ever get the chance to talk to each other, and *Pacific Rim* also failed because the female lead was the only notable woman in the movie.

Pacific Rim's failure to pass the Bechdel test inspired a similar test named after that character, the Mako Mori test, which is passed when the film has:

1. at least one female character;
2. who gets her own narrative arc;
3. that does not revolve around supporting a man's story.

Regardless of what you intend to gain from these tests, the best way to judge a work is to experience it for yourself.

Comment: Indeed, there are quite a large number of anime that would in fact fail the "reverse Bechdel test" (mostly in the cute-girls-doing-cute-things genre). Kantai Collection has a single male character (the Admiral), and he literally does not speak a word, ever. But Kantai Collection passes Bechdel with flying colors. Does that make Kantai Collection a feminist masterpiece? Of course not. All things considered, the Bechdel test is silly to begin with, and especially silly when applied to anime.